# Using incr-tcl with version 8.4.19

Tags: oop, tcl, backwards-compatibility, incr-tcl

Is it possible to use incr-tcl when working with tcl version 8.4.19?
Which include packages are required?
Until now we used Active-Tcl version 8.6, which came with incr-tcl built-in. Now we need to support stations that only have version 8.4.19 installed, and I want to know whether there's a technological roadblock or if it's just a matter of installing and referencing additional packages.

Comment: There might be other problems: no `{*}`, no `dict` and many other things are missing in Tcl 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most certainly possible to have [incr Tcl] working with the Tcl 8.4 series.

```
bash$ tclsh8.4
% puts [info patchlevel]
8.4.7
% package require Itcl
3.3
% puts $itcl::patchLevel
3.3b1
```

You might prefer a slightly different version, but that combination works on my system (OSX Leopard).

Comment: @johannes thank you - where can I find a reference to what is supported and what is not?